# Erlang and YAWS setup in Windows

Tags: windows, erlang, yaws

I am trying to setup Erlang with YAWS in Windows. I Installed `otp_win32_R14B03.exe` and it worked fine and I am able to compile Erlang Programs.

I installed `Yaws-1.90-windows-installer.exe`, then from command prompt I tried running 
`YAWS -i` command and I get below error:

```
C:\ERL58~1.4\ERTS-5~1.4\bin\beam.smp.dll unknown flag ->
Usage: beam.smp.dll [flags] [ -- [init_args] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further research I figured out the problem

We need to add C:\Program\erl5.8.4\bin, C:\Program\erl5.8.4\erts-5.8.4\bin,C:\Program\erl5.8.4\lib\yaws-1.90\bin all three to path variable, then yaws works like charm

Comment: yaws installer should add its own paths automatically. I suspect that if you had to add these yaws paths yourself, the installer you used was corrupted

Comment: I just installed yaws.  I only needed to add the erl bin to my path, as mentioned in Muzaaya's answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must have the Full path to erlang's executable scripts in your system environment PATH. usually on windows you will find this path as `C:/Program Files (x86)/erl-5.8.3/bin` . add this path in your PATH environment variable.

The next thing is that the command to start yaws should be `yaws -i`. **NOT** *YAWS -I*  the way you probably entered it in the shell.

Comment: I have already added the Path variable bo bin folder and 'YAWS -I' was a Typo while asking the question, I tried with yaws -i and got the same error, but on further research i figured the problem and have mentioned it below, appreciate your help